# MySql count(*) without group by

Tags: mysql

I have the following table `pet`:

```
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| name     | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| Fluffy   | Harold | cat     | f    | 1993-02-04 | NULL       |
| Claws    | Gwen   | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL       |
| Buffy    | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL       |
| Fang     | Benny  | dog     | m    | 1990-08-27 | NULL       |
| Bowser   | Diane  | dog     | m    | 1989-03-31 | 1995-07-29 |
| Chirpy   | Gwen   | bird    | f    | 1998-09-11 | NULL       |
| Whistler | Gwen   | bird    | NULL | 1997-12-09 | NULL       |
| Slim     | Benny  | snake   | m    | 1996-04-29 | NULL       |
| Puffball | Diane  | hamster | f    | 1999-03-30 | NULL       |
| Jenny    | Robert | dog     | f    | 2004-01-01 | 2014-05-04 |
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
```

I decided to run a query without a `GROUP BY` clause as follows:

`SELECT owner, COUNT(*) FROM pet;`

Got the following:

```
+--------+----------+
| owner  | count(*) |
+--------+----------+
| Harold |       10 |
+--------+----------+
```

I would've thought that `Robert` would've been in the `owner` column since alphabetically it's the last one. Any idea why I got this output?

Comment: I would not count on the "owner" being from any particular row in this query.  Changes to MySQL version, storage engine, or phase of the moon might change which row gets selected in a query like this.  (Just running the query after restoring the data from a backup might affect the results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.** Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which values within each group the server chooses. [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 1):

It should not get the last one, it gets the first owner and then proceeds with COUNT(*) fetching all the rows, thats all the query does.

Comment: It *does not* necessarily get the first owner and this answer should not have been accepted.  It gets an *indeterminate* value as clearly stated in another answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
SELECT MIN(owner), count(*) from pet;
```

This will retrieve the "smaller" owner (in this case, the first one ordered alphabetically).